# Get selected text from bootstrap dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap dropdown, and I want to keep the text of what is selected. I have tried most of the ways tried here, [Get Value From html drop down menu in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30670294/get-value-from-html-drop-down-menu-in-jquery) , but there was never really an answer given, so I am still stuck.

```
<div id="tableDiv" class="dropdown">
    <button id="tableButton" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Table
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul id="tableMenu" class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Att1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Att2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Att3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have a js function that looks as follows

```
$("#tableMenu").click(function(){
  var selText = $("#tableMenu").text();
  document.getElementById("tableButton").innerHTML=selText;
});
```

but as explained in the above link, $("#tableMenu").text(); returns everything in the dropdown as a string, not just the one wanted. How do I get the text just from the one selected.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to attach the `click()` handler to the `a` element within the `ul` that gets toggled. You can then retrieve the `text()` of that element and set it to the related button. Try this:

```js
$("#tableMenu a").on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // cancel the link behaviour
  var selText = $(this).text();
  $("#tableButton").text(selText);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tableDiv" class="dropdown">
  <button id="tableButton" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Table
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
  <ul id="tableMenu" class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Att1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Att2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Att3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using an actual HTML drop down box and not an unordered list?

```
  <select name="tableMenu" id="tableMenu" class="dropdown-menu">
    <option value="Att1">Att1</option>
    <option value="Att2">Att2</option>
    <option value="Att3">Att3</option>
  </select>
```

You should then be able to use:

```
var selText= document.getElementById("tableMenu").value;
```

Comment: The OP is using bootstrap for styling.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the click event to `li` and using `this` get the selected text and assign to the tab button text

```
$("#tableMenu li").click(function () {
  var selText = $(this).text();
  document.getElementById("tableButton").innerHTML = selText; // $("#tableButton").text(selText); //Using Jquery 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

- Here is a three line capture all Bootstrap drop downs minimal working example and what I use.
- NOTE: In your example, I added class "dropdown-item" to be consistent with Bootstrap.

```js
$(".dropdown-item").on("click", function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().prev().text($(this).text()); // Change the button text.
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="tableDiv" class="dropdown">
  <button id="tableButton" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Table
      <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul id="tableMenu" class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Att1</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Att2</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Att3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```